# Multiple CTE Queries, assign single column value to local variable

Tags: sql, sql-server-2012, common-table-expression

This is my sql query. How can I assign Count_CTE.TotalRecords result to my local assigned variable? anyone please ???

```
DECLARE  @Totalrecords Bigint =0;

;WITH Main_Query_CTE AS(

SELECT 
U.Id,
U.Username,
P.Id as ProfileId,
P.Firstname,
P.Lastname 
FROM   [Dbo].[User] U
INNER JOIN [Profile] P
ON U.Id = P.Userid 
WHERE  AND U.[Status] <>0

),
Count_CTE AS ( SELECT COUNT(*) as TotalRecords FROM Main_Query_CTE )

SELECT * FROM Main_Query_CTE ,Count_CTE
ORDER BY Main_Query_CTE.Id
OFFSET 0 ROWS
FETCH NEXT 20 ROWS ONLY
```

Comment: . . SQL Server does not offer the capability of both returning results and assigning to a variable within the same `SELECT` statement.  Your question is unclear.

Comment: Thanks Gordon for prompt response.
Besides my query result I want to set the output parameter with Total Number of records. But unfortunately SQL Server doesn't offer any way where I can assign single column value to my local declared variable. I am looking for way around to achieve this without using #temp table.

Answer (score 1):

As Gordan said you can't assign a variable AND return the select in the same select statement.  Your best bet if you need to assign a local variable is to just throw the data into a temp table and then do your select off that.  You question is a bit unclear though - not sure what your end goal select is.

```
DECLARE  @Totalrecords Bigint =0;

SELECT 
U.Id,
U.Username,
P.Id as ProfileId,
P.Firstname,
P.Lastname 
into #temp
FROM   [Dbo].[User] U
INNER JOIN [Profile] P
ON U.Id = P.Userid 
WHERE  AND U.[Status] <> 0  

select @Totalrecords = COALESCE(COUNT(*),0) FROM #temp;

SELECT *
FROM #temp
ORDER BY id
OFFSET 0 ROWS
FETCH NEXT 20 ROWS ONLY
```

Comment: Correct me If I am wrong #temp table is very costly in term of performance. I am looking to achieve this without using #temp table.

Comment: @SaadAbbasi  . . . It adds some overhead, but I wouldn't call it "very costly", particularly for what you want to do.

Comment: @SaadAbbasi - as Gordon said it does at a small amount of overhead, but there is no other way to set a local variable AND do a select at the same time.  Your only other option would be to do your select off the table twice and the temp table method should be much faster. If the data set was expected to be small I could say you could use a table variable instead which may be just a bit faster than the temp table, but the same logic applies.

Answer (score 0):

Sorry that I'm late to this party (wish I stopped by in 2019), but why not just return the results in a single query rather than two separate queries?

```
WITH cte AS(
SELECT 
    U.Id,
    U.Username,
    P.Id as ProfileId,
    P.Firstname,
    P.Lastname,
    COUNT(*) OVER(PARTITION BY NULL) AS TotalRecords
FROM [Dbo].[User] U
INNER JOIN [Profile] P ON U.Id = P.Userid 
WHERE U.[Status] <> 0

)

SELECT * FROM cte
ORDER BY Id
OFFSET 0 ROWS
FETCH NEXT 20 ROWS ONLY
```

Comment: Ultimately that probably would have worked but apparently the bigger question was how to get a value saved into a variable while also returning the results.

Comment: @shawnt00 You can't while paging. If pagination wasn't the biggest concern, I would just use @@rowcount to assign to your variable. However, I believe there was a misconception to the performance of a cte vs temp table vs table variable. I believe a cte was not his best option here

I would be more interested in knowing more about the OP's scenario. Real expectations of results (how many users are expected to be stored) or If this is for other code to retrieve (I presume this is the case). If the latter, There is no need to store anything on the server side or do pagination through SQL.